# Spotify Android SDK error

Tags: java, android, spotify

I 'm trying to get information through the Spotify API , everything is fine , but in the response.getType ( ) code enters the ERROR branch, with the following error:

net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED, code: -2, failing url: https://accounts.spotify.com/authorize?client_id=****&response_type=token&redirect_uri=listenit-login%3A%2F%2Fcallback&scope=user-read-private.

Anyone know why?

The code:

```
// TODO: Replace with your client ID
private static final String CLIENT_ID = "****";
// TODO: Replace with your redirect URI
private static final String REDIRECT_URI = "listenit-login://callback";

// Request code that will be passed together with authentication result to the onAuthenticationResult callback
// Can be any integer
private static final int REQUEST_CODE = 1995;

private Player mPlayer;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    AuthenticationClient.logout(this);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    AuthenticationRequest.Builder builder =
            new AuthenticationRequest.Builder(CLIENT_ID, AuthenticationResponse.Type.TOKEN, REDIRECT_URI);
    builder.setScopes(new String[]{"user-read-private"});
    AuthenticationRequest request = builder.build();

    AuthenticationClient.openLoginActivity(this, REQUEST_CODE, request);


}
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);

    // Check if result comes from the correct activity
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE) {
        AuthenticationResponse response = AuthenticationClient.getResponse(resultCode, intent);

        switch (response.getType()) {
            // Response was successful and contains auth token
            case TOKEN:
                Log.d("MainActivity", "User logged in");
                break;

            // Auth flow returned an error
            case ERROR:
                Log.d("MainActivity", response.getError());
                break;

            // Most likely auth flow was cancelled
            default:
                // Handle other cases
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: In order to get support for the Spotify Android SDK, I recommend you to have a look at the [project's GitHub repo](https://github.com/spotify/android-sdk/issues).